# grub 0.97 (legacy) confusion between menu.lst and grub.cfg

Tags: debian, grub

I've been looking through documentation but am still utterly confused.  I'm used to using `menu.lst` to configure grub but `grub.cfg` seems to be the way to do it for grub2.  My Debian 8 server has grub 0.97 installed and seems to have components to use both/either of `menu.lst` or `grub.cfg`.  I can't seem to find any information on how the two interact.

Does grub 0.97 simply use `grub.cfg` if it's there and then defaults to `menu.lst` otherwise?  I had a boot issue and the tech support people where my server resides simply renamed `grub.cfg` to `grub.cf_`.  When I run `update-grub` it doesn't seem to create a new `grub.cfg` and only handles `menu.lst`.

If I wanted to switch over to using `grub.cfg` then do I need to start using `grub-mkconfig` instead (looking through `update-grub` it doesn't seem to ever handle `grub.cfg)?  If`apt`does a kernel upgrade, will the appropriate thing happen and`grub.cfg` be updated?

Answer (score 0):

In grub legacy it uses exclusively menu.lst. In grub2 grub.cfg which you should never modify by your self. If I recall correctly there are commands called grub2-install and update-grub2 on debian that will configure grub.cfg.

Comment: okay, but then why did I have a `grub.cfg` and why does having one cause my system to not boot properly (I assumed it was that it was being used and it was misconfigured).  I also have `/etc/grub.d/` files which seem to be what's used to create the `grub.cfg` file.